# HTML5 Progress Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

### My HTML5 Progress Element

```js
var value = 0, pos = 0,
    progressHidden = false,
    progressEl = $('progress'),
    timer = setInterval(progress, 100);

function progress() {

    // run counter
    value++;
    if (value <= 100) {
        progressEl.val(value);
        pos = 1 - (value / 100);
    }

    // update background
    progressEl.css('background-position', '0 ' + pos + 'em');

    // show/hide progress
    if (progressHidden && value < 100) {
        progressEl.val(0);
        progressEl.removeClass("hidden");
        progressHidden = false;
    }

}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono:700);
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 50px;
 background: #000000;
}
progress {
 appearance: none;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 300px;
 height: 1em;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 font-family: "Ubuntu Mono", sans-serif;
 font-size: 120px;
 transition: height .4s;
}

progress.hidden {
 height: 0;
 transition-delay: .4s;
}

progress::before {
 content: attr(value);
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: .62em;
 color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.2);
 background: linear-gradient( 
  hsla(0,0%,100%,.6),
  hsla(0,0%,100%,.0) 70% ) 
  no-repeat center;
 background-position: inherit;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
}


progress::-webkit-progress-bar,
 progress::-webkit-progress-value {
 background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress max="99"></progress>
```

### Questions

**1). How Can I Use "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif?**

My attempts to replace the Google font which was used in the source for building this HTML5 Progress Element have resulted in the number being cut off or whatnot. I'm new to this feature and have tried playing around with the `font-size`, `line-height` and whatnot with no success. In addition, I much prefer using `px` rather than `em` and upon attempting to convert the likes of the `font-size` within the `:before` sector, more chaos occurs.

Also upon changing the font to `"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif`, each 10th increment seems to glitch the positioning of the text.

**2). How Can I Add A Percentage (%) Symbol?**

Instead of a simply numeric counter from 0 to 100, I would like to add a percentage symbol to the end of the number to indicate the percentage loaded.

**3). How Can I Implement A Colour Tween?**

Starting with red I would then like to tween to orange and then tween to green as the percentage draws closer to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var value = 0, pos = 0,
    progressHidden = false,
    progressEl = $('progress'),
    timer = setInterval(progress, 100);

function progress() {

    // run counter
    value++;
    if (value <= 100) {
        progressEl.val(value);
        pos = 1 - (value / 100);
  if(value == '10') {
   $('progress').addClass('ten');
  }
  if(value == '100') {
   $('progress').addClass('hundred');
  }
    }
    // update background
    progressEl.css('background-position', '0 ' + pos + 'em');

    // show/hide progress
    if (progressHidden && value < 100) {
        progressEl.val(0);
        progressEl.removeClass("hidden");
        progressHidden = false;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 50px;
 background: #000000;
}
progress {
 appearance: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 450px;
 height: 1.4em;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 font-size: 120px;
 transition: height .4s;
}
progress.hidden {
 height: 0;
 transition-delay: .4s;
}
progress::before {
 content: attr(value);
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: .80em;
 color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.2);
 background: linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background: -o-linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background: -ms-linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background-position: inherit;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
}
progress::after {
 content: '%';
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 190px;
  bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: .80em;
 color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.2);
 background: linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background: -o-linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background: -ms-linear-gradient( green, orange ) no-repeat center;
 background-position: inherit;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
}
progress.ten::after {
  right: 100px;
}
progress.hundred::after {
  right: 0px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar,
 progress::-webkit-progress-value {
 background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress max="99"></progress>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done? Also, although the colour gradient looks okay, I was looking more for a one tone colour tween if this is possible.

Comment: I did not do anything with javascript. I just changed in CSS. 

progress::before, progress::after (you can change gradient colors)

Comment: How does your "%" show and can you make it so that it is relative to the current percent instead of having a large space between 0-9, less of a space at 10-99 and correct at 100?

Comment: Brother I just updated the code according to your requirements. Please do check and mark this thread as solved. :)

Comment: Very nice, it doesn't tween from red through to green however this is good enough to accept as an answer, plus I never actually thought about a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use the following to change color. But rest queries, I could not figure out too.

```
                    background: #ffffff; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
                    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(green,red); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
                    background: -o-linear-gradient(green,red); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
                    background: -moz-linear-gradient(green,red); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
                    background: linear-gradient(green,red); /* Standard syntax */
```

Comment: I'm looking more for a colour tween rather than a colour gradient howver thank you for your answer.